# When proving two congruence how do we know which angle/letter comes?

Tags: triangles, congruences

Like lets say this is the picture [image]

Like how would i know which angle comes first for example After proving which angle congruent to which, how do i write. Triangle VTU =/congruent to CTB or Triangle TUV is congruent to Triangle TBC. What was the general idea?

Comment: If you write $VTU\cong CTB$ then $\angle V = \angle C$ and $VT=CT$ and so on.

Comment: So as long the angles i write to prove are congruent, it doesn't matter right?

Comment: So as long as my proven triangle is congruent to the one i equaled, it doesn't matter right?

Comment: Not really, if you write $UTV\cong CTB$ instead, it would have meant $UT=CT$ and $\angle U = \angle C$ which is different from $VTU\cong CTB$

Comment: But the first example you showed me wasn't congruent as ∠U ≅ ∠C my question was for example lets say angle t is congruent to angle i and angle y is congruent to angle W and angle c is congruent to H. lets say T and Y is congruent to I and W and C Y is congruent to H W. can i write like triangle TYC ≅ iWH...and even if i flip the angles like i put C instead of T in the beginning and H instead of I in the beginning of the other one...is it the same or will it matter..my question is that as long as its congruent will the order matter?

Comment: In general, the order matters.